# Performing lots of string concatenation in C?

Tags: c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm porting some code from Java to C, and so far things have gone well.

However, I have a particular function in Java that makes liberal use of `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
// .. build string out of variable-length data
for (SolObject object : this) {
    result.append(object.toString());
}
// .. some parts are conditional
if (freezeCount < 0) result.append("]");
else result.append(")");
```

I realize SO is not a code translation service, but I'm not asking for anyone to translate the above code.

I'm wondering how to efficiently perform this type of mass string concatenation in C. It's mostly small strings, but each is determined by a condition, so I can't combine them into a simple `sprintf` call.

How can I reliably do this type of string concatenation?

Comment: Are you strictly using C? or can you use C++ as well?

Comment: Well you could combine them in a bunch of sprintf() calls. Just use the return value ...

Comment: @Nico I'm using plain C, and I'd like to avoid C++.

Comment: Then: what is  `result`? some kind of struct with function pointers (lots of them) ? BTW: in C the colon is only used in bitfields and in labels.

Comment: @wildplasser: It's java.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well: everybody wants the colon ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather "clever" way to conver a number of "objects" to string is:

```
 char buffer[100];
 char *str = buffer;
 str += sprintf(str, "%06d", 123);
 str += sprintf(str, "%s=%5.2f", "x", 1.234567);
```

This is fairly efficient, since sprintf returns the length of the string copied, so we can "move" str forward by the return value, and keep filling in.

Of course, if there are true Java Objects, then you'll need to figure out how to make a Java style ToString function into "%somethign" in C's printf family.

Comment: Just make sure that whatever you're `sprintf`-ing isn't longer than 99 characters (leave one `char` for the terminating null character) or you'll get a buffer overrun and, probably, a segmentation fault.

Comment: I ended up doing this with a check for buffer overrun (with a `reallocf` if it does). I figure I'll optimize it more later if it ends up being a problem, but for now, this looks really elegant!

Answer (score 2):

The performance problem with `strcat()` is that it has to scan the destination string to find the terminating `\0'` before it can start appending to it.

But remember that `strcat()` doesn't take *strings* as arguments, it takes *pointers*.

If you maintain a separate pointer that always points to the terminating `'\0'` of the string you're appending to, you can use that pointer as the first argument to `strcat()`, and it won't have to re-scan it every time. For that matter, you can use `strcpy()` rater than `strcat()`.

Maintaining the value of this pointer and ensuring that there's enough room are left as an exercise.

NOTE: you can use `strncat()` to avoid overwriting the end of the destination array (though it will silently truncate your data). I don't recommend using `strncpy()` for this purpose. See [my rant on the subject](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

If your system supports them, the (non-standard) `strcpy()` and `strlcat()` functions can be useful for this kind of thing. They both return the total length of the string they tried to create. But their use makes your code less portable; on the other hand, there are open-source implementations that you can use anywhere.

Another solution is to call `strlen()` on the string you're appending. This isn't ideal, since it's then scanned twice, once by `strcat()` and once by `strlen()` -- but at least it avoids re-scanning the entire destination string.

Comment: "Maintaining the value of this pointer and ensuring that there's enough room are left as an exercise." But it seems there's not a good way to do this with the standard string functions. Unfortunately the standard string functions don't return a pointer to the terminating `\0`, but to the start of the string. Other string libraries are needed to solve this limitation, I think.

Comment: You could always run strlen on incoming strings yourself and use mem* set of functions to avoid another strlen call. (to keep track of memory and string tail)

Answer (score 2):

The cause of poor performance when concatenating strings is the reallocation of memory.  Joel Spolsky discusses this in his article [Back to basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).  He describes the naive method of concatenating strings:

> Shlemiel gets a job as a street painter, painting the dotted lines down the middle of the road. On the first day he takes a can of paint out to the road and finishes 300 yards of the road. "That's pretty good!" says his boss, "you're a fast worker!" and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel only gets 150 yards done. "Well, that's not nearly as good as yesterday, but you're still a fast worker. 150 yards is respectable," and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel paints 30 yards of the road. "Only 30!" shouts his boss. "That's unacceptable! On the first day you did ten times that much work! What's going on?"
>
> "I can't help it," says Shlemiel. "Every day I get farther and farther away from the paint can!"

If you can, you want to know how large your destination buffer needs to be before allocating it.  The only realistic way to do this is to call `strlen` on all of the strings you want to concatenate.  Then allocate the appropriate amount of memory and use a slightly modified version of `strncpy` that returns a pointer to the end of the destination buffer.

```
// Copies src to dest and returns a pointer to the next available
// character in the dest buffer.
// Ensures that a null terminator is at the end of dest.  If
// src is larger than size then size - 1 bytes are copied
char* StringCopyEnd( char* dest, char* src, size_t size )
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    if ( size == 0 ) return dest;

    while ( pos < size - 1 && *src )
    {
        *dest = *src;
        ++dest;
        ++src;
        ++pos;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Note how you have to set the `size` parameter to be the number of bytes left until the end of the destination buffer.

Here's a sample test function:

```
void testStringCopyEnd( char* str1, char* str2, size_t size )
{
    // Create an oversized buffer and fill it with A's so that 
    // if a string is not null terminated it will be obvious.
    char* dest = (char*) malloc( size + 10 ); 
    memset( dest, 'A', size + 10 );
    char* end = StringCopyEnd( dest, str1, size );
    end = StringCopyEnd( end, str2, size - ( end - dest ) );
    printf( "length:  %d - '%s'\n", strlen( dest ), dest );
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Test with a large enough buffer size to concatenate 'Hello World'.
    // and then reduce the buffer size from there
    for ( int i = 12; i > 0; --i )
    {
        testStringCopyEnd( "Hello", " World", i );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces:

```
length:  11 - 'Hello World'
length:  10 - 'Hello Worl'
length:  9 - 'Hello Wor'
length:  8 - 'Hello Wo'
length:  7 - 'Hello W'
length:  6 - 'Hello '
length:  5 - 'Hello'
length:  4 - 'Hell'
length:  3 - 'Hel'
length:  2 - 'He'
length:  1 - 'H'
length:  0 - ''
```

Comment: NOTE: this is a terribele answer (very much comparable to the dreaded strncpy()):: it will **always** leave the target string unterminated.

Comment: @wildplasser I've added a comment that it will never terminate the dest string and made sure the calling code ensures there will be a null terminator.

Comment: It still is terrible, IMnsvHO. You only pose by means of name dropping (BTW Joel Spolsky has a C++ accent, so you are in good company) Keeping the NUL-termination as a task for the caller is a very bad habit, in terms of API-design. strings are strings. deal with it) Note: I don't downvote. I never do. People who believe this, deserve to lose, IMHO.

Comment: BTW: identfiers/function names starting with "str", followed by a lowercase letter are reserved for future use by the standard library.

Comment: Changed function name and ensured that a null terminator is always appended.

Comment: It will still leave the target string unterminated if the source strings just happens to *almost fit* (just like the dreaded strncpy()).

Comment: @wildplasser - I'm pretty sure it doesn't.  I did realise there was a redundant if check for `*dest = '\0'` though.  The `size - 1` in the loop ensures that this will be ok.  I've added a test function and test output.

Answer (score 1):

If operations like these are very frequent, you could implement them in your own buffer class. Example (error handling omitted for brevity ;-):

```
struct buff {
        size_t used;
        size_t size;
        char *data;
        } ;

struct buff * buff_new(size_t size)
{
struct buff *bp;
bp = malloc (sizeof *bp);
bp->data = malloc (size);
bp->size = size;
bp->used = 0;
return bp;
}

void buff_add_str(struct buff *bp, char *add)
{
size_t len;
len = strlen(add);

        /* To be implemented: buff_resize() ... */
if (bp->used + len +1 >= bp->size) buff_resize(bp, bp->used+1+len);

memcpy(buff->data + buff->used, add, len+1);

buff->used += len;
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the strings look so small, I'd be inclined just to use `strcat` and revisit if performance becomes an issue.

You could make your own method that remembers the string length so it doesn't need to iterate through the string to find the end (which is potentially the slow bit of strcat if you are doing lots of appends to long strings)